# Computing $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^{+}}\psi(\varepsilon)/\Gamma(\varepsilon)$ with asymptotic expansions

Tags: limits, asymptotics, gamma-function, limits-without-lhopital, digamma-function

I have the following limit of which I want to compute:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^{+}} \frac{\psi(\varepsilon)}{\Gamma(\varepsilon)}.
\end{equation}

For $\varepsilon\approx 0$ and $\varepsilon\neq 0$ I have the following limiting forms
\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
\psi(\varepsilon)=-\frac{1}{\varepsilon}-\gamma+O(\varepsilon)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\tag{2}
\frac{1}{\Gamma(\varepsilon)}=\varepsilon+O(\varepsilon^{2}).
\end{equation}

If I multiply $(1)$ and $(2)$ together we get
\begin{align}
\tag{3}
\frac{\psi(\varepsilon)}{\Gamma(\varepsilon)}
&=
-1-\frac{O(\varepsilon^{2})}{\varepsilon}
-\gamma\varepsilon-\gamma O(\varepsilon^{2})
+\varepsilon O(\varepsilon)+O(\varepsilon)O(\varepsilon^{2})\\
&=
-1-O(\varepsilon)
-\gamma\varepsilon-\gamma O(\varepsilon^{2})
+O(\varepsilon^{2})+O(\varepsilon^{3}).
\end{align}

In the limit, all of the terms with $\varepsilon$ approach zero such that we arrive at
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^{+}} \frac{\psi(\varepsilon)}{\Gamma(\varepsilon)} =
-1.
\end{equation}

I have checked this answer against WolframAlpha which yields the same result. Despite getting the same result, I have doubts as to if this is a sound approach to computing the limit.

> **My question is this: Is the use of asymptotic expansions in this manner proper (i.e. is this a valid method to computing my limit)? Or does it just happen to work out in this example?**

Comment: Why would you suspect that the method is invalid?

Comment: @MarkViola I have never worked with asymptotics before.  This was just my approach based on intuition and intuition can often be misleading in mathematics! Are you insinuating that the approach is valid?

Comment: It is valid.  $O(f(x))=g(x)$ as $x\to a$ means that there exists a number $C>0$ and a number $\delta>0$ such that $|g(x)|\le C|f(x)|$ for all $|x-a|<\delta$.

Comment: @MarkViola Thank you for the explanation Mark.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could take the following method:
\begin{align}
\frac{\psi(x)}{\Gamma(x)} &= \frac{\Gamma(x) \, \psi(x)}{\Gamma^{2}(x)} = \frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma^{2}(x)} \\
&= - \frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}\right).
\end{align}
Now make use of the Taylor series expansion of the inverse of the Gamma function, namely,
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(x)} \approx x + \gamma \, x^{2} + \left(\frac{\gamma^{2}}{2} - \frac{\pi^{2}}{12}\right) \, x^{3} + \mathcal{O}(x^{4})$$
then
$$\frac{\psi(x)}{\Gamma(x)} \approx - \left(1 + 2 \gamma \, x + \left(\frac{3 \, \gamma^{2}}{2} - \frac{\pi^{2}}{4}\right) \, x^{2} + \mathcal{O}(x^{3}) \right).$$

Taking the limit as $x \to 0$ leads to
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\psi(x)}{\Gamma(x)} = -1.$$